# How to get a list of all the check-ins and the work items related in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I am trying to get a list of all the check-ins and the work items that were related to it. I know you can get a history of all the commits and the change sets and once you click on a particular change set, you can view the work item. However, we are creating some statistics and I want the list of check-ins and the work-items that were related to it. I don't want to click on each changeset and get the related work item manually. It will take too much time. If they are also next to the changesets, that will be nice.

If this can be achieved through TFS, I am open to that too.

My team is using the VS Professional 2015 and TFS 2015

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use TFS api (both .net api and REST api) to get the list.

- .net api, check this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/02/01/listing-the-work-items-associated-with-changesets-for-a-path/

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using Microsoft.TeamFoundation;
  using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
  using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

  namespace ListWorkItems
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              if (args.Length < 2)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Usage: listworkitems <URL for TFS><server path>");
                  Environment.Exit(1);
              }

              TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(newUri(args[0]));
              VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService < VersionControlServer();

              // Get the changeset artifact URIs for each changeset in the history query
              List<String> changesetArtifactUris = new List<String>();

              foreach (Object obj in vcs.QueryHistory(args[1],                       // path we care about ($/project/whatever) 
                                                      VersionSpec.Latest,            // version of that path
                                                      0,                             // deletion ID (0 = not deleted) 
                                                      RecursionType.Full,            // entire tree - full recursion
                                                      null,                          // include changesets from all users
                                                      new ChangesetVersionSpec(1),   // start at the beginning of time
                                                      VersionSpec.Latest,            // end at latest
                                                      25,                            // only return this many
                                                      false,                         // we don't want the files changed
                                                      true))                         // do history on the path
              {
                  Changeset c = obj as Changeset;
                  changesetArtifactUris.Add(c.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri);
              }

              // We'll use the linking service to get information about the associated work items
              ILinking linkingService = tpc.GetService<ILinking>();
              LinkFilter linkFilter = new LinkFilter();
              linkFilter.FilterType = FilterType.ToolType;
              linkFilter.FilterValues = new String[1] { ToolNames.WorkItemTracking };  // we only want work itms

              // Convert the artifact URIs for the work items into strongly-typed objects holding the properties rather than name/value pairs 
              Artifact[] artifacts = linkingService.GetReferencingArtifacts(changesetArtifactUris.ToArray(), new LinkFilter[1] { linkFilter });
              AssociatedWorkItemInfo[] workItemInfos = AssociatedWorkItemInfo.FromArtifacts(artifacts);

              // Here we'll just print the IDs and titles of the work items
              foreach (AssociatedWorkItemInfo workItemInfo in workItemInfos)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Id: " + workItemInfo.Id + " Title: " + workItemInfo.Title);
              }
          }
      }

      internal class AssociatedWorkItemInfo
      {
          private AssociatedWorkItemInfo()
          {
          }

          public int Id
          {
              get
              {
                  return m_id;
              }
          }

          public String Title
          {
              get
              {
                  return m_title;
              }
          }

          public String AssignedTo
          {
              get
              {
                  return m_assignedTo;
              }
          }

          public String WorkItemType
          {
              get
              {
                  return m_type;
              }
          }

          public String State
          {
              get
              {
                  return m_state;
              }
          }

          internal static AssociatedWorkItemInfo[] FromArtifacts(IEnumerable<Artifact> artifacts)
          {
              if (null == artifacts)
              {
                  return new AssociatedWorkItemInfo[0];
              }

              List<AssociatedWorkItemInfo> toReturn = new List<AssociatedWorkItemInfo>();

              foreach (Artifact artifact in artifacts)
              {
                  if (artifact == null)
                  {
                      continue;
                  }

                  AssociatedWorkItemInfo awii = new AssociatedWorkItemInfo();

                  // Convert the name/value pairs into strongly-typed objects containing the work item info 
                  foreach (ExtendedAttribute ea in artifact.ExtendedAttributes)
                  {
                      if (String.Equals(ea.Name, "System.Id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                      {
                          int workItemId;

                          if (Int32.TryParse(ea.Value, out workItemId))
                          {
                              awii.m_id = workItemId;
                          }
                      }
                      else if (String.Equals(ea.Name, "System.Title", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                      {
                          awii.m_title = ea.Value;
                      }
                      else if (String.Equals(ea.Name, "System.AssignedTo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                      {
                          awii.m_assignedTo = ea.Value;
                      }
                      else if (String.Equals(ea.Name, "System.State", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                      {
                          awii.m_state = ea.Value;
                      }
                      else if (String.Equals(ea.Name, "System.WorkItemType", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                      {
                          awii.m_type = ea.Value;
                      }
                  }

                  Debug.Assert(0 != awii.m_id, "Unable to decode artifact into AssociatedWorkItemInfo object.");

                  if (0 != awii.m_id)
                  {
                      toReturn.Add(awii);
                  }
              }

              return toReturn.ToArray();
          }

          private int m_id;
          private String m_title;
          private String m_assignedTo;
          private String m_type;
          private String m_state;
      }
  }
  ```
- REST api, check https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#Getlistofassociatedworkitems

  GET /tfvc/changesets/{id}/workitems?api-version={version}